# Efficient async call in Pipe angular2

Tags: asynchronous, service, angular, pipe

I am trying to get an address conversion of longitude and latitude values via the google maps api. I have looked into the angular2 pipe example concerning impure pipes (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html), and this indeed gives me a working piece of code (pure pipes result into null)

The only problem is, that the http call is being done multiple times, because of the impure pipe. The data does not change anymore, and needs to be converted only once.

The pipe:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';

@Pipe({name: 'location', pure: false})
export class LocationPipe implements PipeTransform {

private readableLocation = null;
private fetchedJson = null;
private prevUrl = '';

constructor(private http:Http) {}

transform(location:string):string {
if (location !== this.prevLoc) {
  var arr = location.split(",", 2);
  var lat = arr[0];
  console.log(lat);
  var lon = arr[1];
  console.log(lon);
  var url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + lat + ',' + lon + '&sensor=true';
  console.log(url);

    this.prevLoc = location;
    this.fetchedJson = null;
    this.http.get(url)
    .map( result => result.json() )
    .subscribe( result => this.fetchedJson = result );
  }
  if (this.fetchedJson != null) {
    return this.fetchedJson.results[0].formatted_address;
  }
  return this.fetchedJson;

 }
}
```

The HTML:

```
<td>{{log.location | location}}</td>
```

The 'log' data is received from the backend via a service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';

export class Log {
  _id: Object;
  username: string;
  status: boolean;
  location: string;
  modelName: string;
  searchTerm: string;
  created: number;

  static create(data){
    console.log("New log created and added to the list:");
    console.log(data);
    return new Log(data);
  }

  constructor(data){
    this._id = data._id;
    this.username = data.username;
    this.status = data.status;
    this.location = data.location;
    this.modelName = data.modelName;
    this.searchTerm = data.searchTerm;
    this.created = data.created;
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class LogService {

  public logs;

  constructor(private http: Http){

    this.logs = http.get('https://arest-api.herokuapp.com/users?userStatus=true')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .map(rawUsers => rawUsers.map(Log.create));
  }
}
```

log.location contains the lon and lat values in string format: "51.993398,4.386851"

It takes some seconds for the data to load and display, although it contains only 2 records.
Is there perhaps any better/faster/more efficient way of getting the same result?

Thank you so much for your help! Please let me know if any more information is needed.

**edit**: moving up the caching results in only two requests. Though the question remains whether this could be implemented in a better/more efficient way? The impure pipe is still called upon many times, while the data does not change.

Comment: Cache the result. If the requested location is the same as before, return the cached value. What was the problem with pure pipe?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I am caching the url, that contains the same location, I will try caching the location string. A pure pipe is only executed once (if I understood it correctly), meaning it returns null, as the http request has no result yet.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer moving the location caching up to the beginning of the transform, indeed leads to only 2 requests. Still, as the pipe is impure, it is called upon more than once, while the value does not change. Is there no better way to implement this?

Comment: You can try returning a `Promise` or `Observable` and chain it with `async` `{{log.location | location | async}}`

Comment: There is nothing you can do to make an impure pipe **not** being called often. That's the purpose of an impure pipe to be called for every change detection cycle.

Comment: I totally agree to that. So you state that changing the LogService to return an Observable instead of a Log instance, and chain the location pipe with async would be a better solution then the one I am using now? Could you perhaps explain that in more detail to me?

Comment: I wasn't talking about your LogService to return an observable. I was talking about the pipe because you mentioned that it can't immediately return a value because of the async call it has to make before. I didn't fully investigate your code. Perhaps an observable for your LogService code might help as well.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I will play around a bit with different solutions!